# Drawing to Surface from JNI while moving SurfaceView around

Tags: android, android-ndk, surfaceview

In my application I have a `SurfaceView` in my Activity layout so its surface is not affected by any Fragment lifecycles. I use the surface to draw to it from JNI using following code (some of the varialbes are global):

```
void onDraw() {
    int height=0, width=0;
    ANativeWindow_Buffer nativeBuffer;
    ARect redrawRect;

    if (nativeWindow != NULL) {
        height = ANativeWindow_getHeight(nativeWindow);
        width = ANativeWindow_getWidth(nativeWindow);

        redrawRect.left = 0;
        redrawRect.top = 0;
        redrawRect.right = width;
        redrawRect.bottom = height;
    
        if (ANativeWindow_lock(nativeWindow, &nativeBuffer, &redrawRect) == 0) {
            height = (redrawRect.bottom - redrawRect.top);
            width = (redrawRect.right - redrawRect.left);
    
            bufferSize= height * width * 4;
            memcpy(nativeBuffer.bits, pbuf, bufferSize);
            ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(nativeWindow);
        }
    }
}
```

As long as I do not change the size and position of the `SurfaceView` this works great. However, when I start drawing, adjust the `SurfaceView` in size and position (content is adjusted fine), stop the drawing and then start it again I get the following error:

> E/BufferQueue: [SurfaceView] connect: already connected (cur=2, req=2)

What I understand from the [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics?hl=en) so far is that my `SurfaceView` is the consumer and the `ANativeWindow` the producer. The SurfaceView holds a `BufferQueue` which send the display data (copied by memcpy) from the producer to the consumer side. So after the size and location change one of them (I'm not sure which) is trying to connect to that BufferQueue again. Since in my code I'm not calling `queue/acquire` etc. specifically I'm not sure how to prevent this.

What I do not know: Is connect called from `ANativeWindow_lock` or `ANativeWindow_fromSurface` on the NDK side? Could the buffer received by the lock method leak somehow to prevent the connect next time? I also added log messages to the lock and unlock results and found that after the size and location change `ANativeWindow_lock` fails. This seems odd to me because my unlock is only performed when the lock was successful and I'm not locking the surface from the Java side at all. If I try to unlock it then from JNI I get:

> Surface::unlockAndPost failed, no locked buffer

I also thought about other memory leaks and analysed it with LeakCanary. This does not find any leaks, even when I do a heap dump manually tho I'm not sure how good it works with native code.

If I do not draw at all this error does not appear. Do you have any ideas for this?

If it matters I'm developing on Android KitKat (4.4.2). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Resizing the Surface is done by the SurfaceFlinger and you cannot draw while the resizing/moving is in progress. You have to detect when the Window is moving/resizing and stop try to Lock it for drawing.

Comment: I resize my SurfaceView when switching between two Fragments. So what you are saying is that I should lock the surface during that transaction and release it when the transaction is over? Are `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost` the right methods for this?

Comment: Lock/Unlock are used when you want to CHANGE pixels: to prevend others (other Threads) from do changes when you're currently working on same Surface. You have to RELASE all locks (the amount of lockCanvas() should be the same of unlock()) and wait untile the Surface is free to be locked or Available. If I remember well there is a method for check SurfaceView availability before try to lock the Canvas.

Comment: While the SurfaceView is held by SurfaceFlinger (or others) you have to stop to draw on it. Then you have to be sure to have called unlockCanvas() the same amount of time of the locking method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try that tomorrow! But why does it works the first time (as long as I do not stop the drawing the content moves and scales fine) tho?

Comment: There are many "connect: already connected" issues online (of course not natively in JNI, however the causes are the same).